# PHP/MSSQL not returning records

Tags: php, sql-server

The following code block is a function contained within a class that queries a database and fetches the required results. The query sent is dependant on what the property product_type_id is set to. When the function is called, the `<table>` tags are echoed but it will not enter the `while` loop, which leads me to believe the SQL query is not running. The tables have been populated with data, and the MSSQL server is up, and no error is being returned.
Using MSSQL 2012, IIS10.0 and PHP 7.1 in a development environment only. Other database queries within the site run successfully. Any ideas? Thanks

```
public function build_product_list()
    {
        // This function builds the product list visible on the main site
        try
        {
            if($this->product_type_id === "0")
            {
                $query = 'SELECT sp.product_id, sp.product_name, sp.product_price, pt.product_type_name FROM shop_products AS sp LEFT JOIN product_types AS pt ON sp.product_type_id = pt.product_type_id ORDER BY sp.product_type_id ASC ';
            }
            else
            {
                $query = 'SELECT sp.product_id, sp.product_name, sp.product_price, pt.product_type_name FROM shop_products AS sp LEFT JOIN product_types AS pt ON sp.product_type_id = pt.product_type_id WHERE sp.product_type_id = :product_type_id ORDER BY sp.product_id ASC';
            }
            $stmt = $this->dbcore_prod_core->dbc->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':product_type_id', $this->product_type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $rowcount = 0;
            echo '<table>';
            while($product_fetch = $stmt->fetch())
            {
                if($rowcount%3 == 0)
                {
                    if($rowcount > 0)
                    {
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    echo '<tr>';
                }
                echo '<td>Product Name:' . $product_fetch['product_name'] . '<br />Product ID:' . $product_fetch['product_id'] . '<br />Delivery Frequency:' . $product_fetch['product_type_name'] . '<br />Price:' . $product_fetch['product_price'] . '</td>';
                $rowcount++;
            }
            echo '</table>';

        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            exit($this->err_handle->generate_error("product_list_unavailable", "db", $e));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); print_r($result);` before `$rowcount = 0;` and see if query is returning the correct result.

Comment: all I get is array( )

Comment: Check your query then. There must be some issue with that. Cheers!

Comment: I know where I have gone wrong....answer to follow.

Comment: what do you mean by "Answer to follow"?

Comment: Just posted my answer.

Comment: haha, holy crap, yeah! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where I went wrong. I forgot to add `$stmt->execute();` after substituting the `product_type_id` value, meaning the function wasn't able to fetch the data in the first place, hence why the `while` loop wasn't running.